# ffmpeg - slideshow from set of images ignoring first image

Tags: linux, image, ffmpeg

I can create slideshow with below command

```
ffmpeg -y -f image2 -r 1/15 -i image%d.jpeg -y -r 45 video.mp4
```

Video is created successfully ,, but its ignoring the 1st image..

for example in current folder i have

```
image1.jpeg
image2.jpeg
image3.jpeg
```

but slide show is created with `image2.jpeg` and `image3.jpeg` only..(i.e 30 second video with 2 image is created..but i expected 45 second video with 3 images displaying 15 sec per image)

Comment: same issue for me ... can some one help this ?

Comment: @AnishaVirat See the answer below if you haven't already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong with your command is the `-r 45` as an output option. You're telling ffmpeg to produce a video with 45 fps output rate. You probably don't want that.

Use the `fps` filter to set the framerate:

```
ffmpeg -r 1/15 -i img%d.jpeg -vf fps=25 output.mp4
```

If you use

```
ffmpeg -r 1/15 -i img%d.jpeg output.mp4
```

you will get a video with ~0.07 fps, and three frames, meaning a roughly 45 second long video (*3 / 0.07*). This gives the expected result, but it might not be playable in all players.

Note:

- `-y` is not needed twice. Only supply it once before `-i`.
- `-f image2` is not needed.

<sub>Using `-r` as an output option to force another frame rate skips the first frame immediately in some players. I consider this a bug, which is now [reported in this ticket](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3164) .</sub>

Comment: woow just saw your ticket...and ffmpeg support looks impressive :o

Comment: you are pretty active aswel :) +1 for your solution..will try and report you

Comment: and actually i thought 45 as the video length  :/

Comment: Well, the length will be calculated automatically. If you have 3 frames and each one's shown for 15 seconds, ffmpeg will stop encoding after the third frame. To cut after a specific length, use the `-t` option.

Comment: hey .. i used the command ffmpeg -r 1/15 -y -i image/image%d.jpeg -vf fps=25 video.mp4 ..but still i get the 30 second video...1st image just goes away immediately

Comment: Make sure you use a recent version of ffmpeg, by compiling it yourself or downloading a static build from the homepage. If it doesn't work, please include the full, uncut command line output in your question as well. Thanks.

Comment: yea i compiled latest version just last week from github...and i run via php .. i get this output [libx264 @ 0x1aeb100] kb/s:73.27